# What's the difference between 才 and 就？

Tags: meaning, difference

I know one stands for "slow than expected" and the other for turnover "earlier". In some cases, I cannot explain to myself their position in sentences. Can you explain to me in more detail the meaning of ? And the difference between 才是，就是

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about them being used to describe the sequence of events-- both terms have many many unrelated uses and are very complicated characters.  If you clarify these types of questions a bit more it will avoid possible confusion, and it will help  make sure you get better answers :)

if in doubt including example sentences for grammar/vocab use questions is always best-- context is king in chinese.

---

At the basics the two are opposites, early vs late.  However chinese isn't ever that firmly set in stone.  Here is an article from allset learning chinese wiki, a great source for basic grammar questions if you haven't seen it before:

https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Comparing_%22cai%22_and_%22jiu%22

This should help get an idea of the common use for sequence of events with these terms.

Answer (score 1):

才 has multiple uses. It can be used to indicate "unexpected delay or late in arrival", such as "你怎麼**才**來呢？" - "How come you come/arrive **so** late?" When used with 是(is, am, are), it emphasizes one's own argument against the other's argument with certainty, for example:

- 我不是賊, 你**才**是. - I am not a thief, you **certainly/indeed** are (a thief).

Same to 才, 就 has many uses. It can be used to indicate something "turned... earlier" without noticing, or simply "already", such as "他**早就**長大了" - "He has grown up **already**", which really means "He has turned into a man in earlier days without your noticing."

When used with 是, it can mean "only/merely",

- 大家都来了,**就是**小林还没有来 - Everybody has came already, **only** 小林 has not yet arrived.

or mean "even if",

- **就是**下雨,我们也要开工 - **Even if** it is raining, we will start working anyway.

and as a conjunction - "either ... or"

- 这几天,不是刮风,**就是**下雨 - These few days, **either** windy **or** rainy.

Let's compare **才是** and **就是** using previous example:

- A: 你是賊. (A simple accusation/argument.)
- B: 我不是賊, 你**才是**. (才 emphasis own accusation/argument in hit back.)
- A: 你**就是**賊. (就 supports the original accusation/argument with emphasis.)

Answer (score 0):

茶馆文化才是最具成都特色的休闲方式。 Visiting the tea house is a really special leisure time activity in Chengdu. The word 才 is an adverb, in this sentence meaning “really” or “very.”
就是 just
就是因为我喜欢他
just because I like him

Answer (score -2):

let me try, most of the time...
才:indeed
就：merely

才是: is..., indeed.
就是：is..., merely.

我才是我， i am myself, indeed.
我就是我， i am myself, merely.